# Is there any Way to show Empty GridView On pageLoad event?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

Hope You all Are Fine

Can any one help me kindly i have a grid view that fetch tha record from database but show all the previous data which i entered by the grid but now i want to show the all data which i entering till the pageload even called, when page load that should not show all the entered records.
Thanks in Advance

Here is my code behind work

```
  protected void BindData()
        {
            SqlConnection conne = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.0.65;Initial Catalog=TestDataBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=mushko");

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();

            conne.Open();

            string cmdstr = "SELECT * FROM OPR1 ";

            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conne);

            SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

            adp.Fill(ds);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            conne.Close();
            GridView1.DataSource = ds;
            GridView1.DataBind();
         //   GridView1.DataSource =null;

           // GridView1.DataSource = ds;
          //  GridView1.DataBind();
            //ds = null;
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {
            SqlConnection conne = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.0.65;Initial Catalog=TestDataBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=mushko");

            conne.Open();

            if (e.CommandName.Equals("ADD"))
            {

                Calendar txtOpenDate = (Calendar)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtOpenDate");

                TextBox txtCloseDate = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtCloseDate");

                DropDownList DropDownListoppr = (DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownListoppr");

                DropDownList DropDownListStages = (DropDownList)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("DropDownListStages");

                TextBox txtAddLine = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddLine");

                TextBox txtStages = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtStages");

                TextBox txtAddOppId = (TextBox)GridView1.FooterRow.FindControl("txtAddOppId");




                string cmdstr = "insert into OPR1(OpenDate,CloseDate,SlpCode,Step_Id,Line,OpprId) values(@txtOpenDate,@txtCloseDate,@SlpCode,@Step_Id,@txtAddLine,@txtAddOppId)";

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conne);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtOpenDate", txtOpenDate.TodaysDate);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtCloseDate", txtCloseDate.Text);


                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Step_Id", DropDownListStages.SelectedValue.ToString()); // SelectedItem.ToString());

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@SlpCode", DropDownListoppr.SelectedValue.ToString()); // SelectedItem.ToString());

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtStages", txtStages.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtAddLine", txtAddLine.Text);

                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@txtAddOppId", txtAddOppId.Text);

                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
             //   this.TextBox1.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.ToString();
           //     this.TextBox3.Text = DropDownList1.SelectedValue.ToString();


                BindData();
                conne.Close();
            }

        }
        protected void GridView1_OnRowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {

            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.Footer)
            {

                DropDownList DropDownListoppr = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownListoppr");
                DropDownList DropDownListStages = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DropDownListStages");

                DataTable CardCode = new DataTable();
                DataTable CardCode1 = new DataTable();

                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Data Source=192.168.0.65;Initial Catalog=TestDataBase;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=sa;Password=mushko");
                using (connection)
                {

                    // SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("select distinct T1.SlpCode,T1.SlpName,T3.StepId,T3.Descript from OSLP T1 left join OPR1 T2 on T1.SlpCode=T2.SlpCode right join OOST T3 on T3.StepId=t2.Step_Id ", connection);

                    SqlCommand theCommand = new SqlCommand("select SlpCode,SlpName from OSLP ", connection);
                    SqlCommand theCommand1 = new SqlCommand("select Distinct StepId, Descript from OOST ", connection);
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(theCommand);
                    SqlDataAdapter adapter1 = new SqlDataAdapter(theCommand1);

                    adapter.Fill(CardCode);
                    adapter1.Fill(CardCode1);
                    //DropDownList7.DataSource = CardCode;
                    //DropDownList7.DataTextField = "SlpName";
                    //DropDownList7.DataValueField = "SlpCode";
                    //DropDownList7.DataBind();

                    if (CardCode.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int i = 0; i < CardCode.Rows.Count; i++)
                        {
                            string name3 = CardCode.Rows[i]["SlpName"].ToString();
                            string slpCode = CardCode.Rows[i]["SlpCode"].ToString();
                            DropDownListoppr.Items.Add(new ListItem(name3, slpCode));



                        }
                    }

                    if (CardCode1.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < CardCode1.Rows.Count; j++)
                        {
                            string name4 = CardCode1.Rows[j]["Descript"].ToString();
                            string stageCode = CardCode1.Rows[j]["StepId"].ToString();
                            DropDownListStages.Items.Add(new ListItem(name4, stageCode));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Where and how are you calling the BindData() method

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           // GridView1.DataSource = null;
         //   gridview1.Columns.Clear();
          //  GridView1.Columns.Clear();
            
         
              
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {

                BindData();
            
             
            }
        }

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the grid empty on page load event, then do not write the code to bind it on Page Load event, instead write the code on"Add Button" click event(if that's what you want).

Answer (score -1):

For showing empty record Grid You can Use EmptyDataTemplate.

For more you can try this [Link](http://codeverge.com/asp.net.presentation-controls/how-to-show-gridview-with-empty/482186)